# Error handling is not working only in release build (MVC5)

Tags: json, iis, exception, internal-server-error, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have an action in a controller that returns error code 500 when an error occurs, along with a message in JSON format, this way:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = Constants.PERFIL_NOMBRE_ADMINISTRADOR)]
    public async Task<JsonResult> ImportUsers(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        try
        {
          // some code
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 500;
            ErrorLog.Save(ex);
            return Json("Existió un problema al subir el archivo. Por favor, intente nuevamente más tarde.");
        }
    }
```

In development environment, when an exception occurs, the web page receives that JSON message and shows it in an alert.

The interesting thing in production is that this does not happen. The JSON message is not returned, and instead the ugly "500 - Internal server error." page is shown.

Can you explain me why this happens and how can I solve it?

Comment: Is this a GET Request? To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonrequestbehavior(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: @JasonBayldon No.. it is POST... I have added the method attributes in the question. However, if it works when developing, I don't think this was the problem.

Comment: [2020] @jstuardo do you still recall how to solve this?